# Default behavior of Input Buffer in SAS while reading data from external file

Tags: sas

Contents of a.txt
22
333
4444
55555

But when i run this code :

```
data numbers;
infile ’c:\a.txt’;
input var 5.;
/* list */ ;
run;
```

the data in numbers.sas is saved as :

```
  333  
55555
```

** Note the format of the data in numbers.sas and the format in a.txt

But when i use the list the input buffer is somewhat like this :

```
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7  
2         333 3    
4         55555 5
```

Why doesnt sas show 1 and 3?? And how is the input buffer reading?
Please explain

Answer (score 3):

Try adding TRUNCOVER to your infile statement or remove the 5. after your input statement. SAS now expects a 5 digit number. If will continue reading if the line on your sourcefile is less then 5 characters long.

```
data numbers;
infile 'c:\a.txt' truncover;
input var 5.;
run;
```

For more infor read this [paper on infile statement](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p009-26.pdf) options